# Google spreadsheet: Sum if with two or more parameters

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a question about 'sum if' with two and more parameters. Here a table:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AvE2P3ZhQySBdDZuOF9Gd040VnlESXRoR0pvaGhkRWc&usp=sharing
now formula make code of each order in Y column. For example: First order have code 23423 because

action - purchase (2 line), Delivery type - Delivery by mail (3 line), Type of payment - partial (4 line), parcel status - sent (2 line), payment - received (3 line)

in H4 we have sum all price with discount wich have 23222 code.

But its too unwieldy and difficult to create new sums. 
So I need in formula or script, which allow me to create this sums fast and easy.

I see script like:

```
=mysumm (C="purchase ";N=" Delivery by mail";P="partial ";V="sent ";X="received ")
```

Answer (score 1):

=DSUM() will do this. Also =Query() will work.

Examples of doing sumif style totals with DSUM etc : http://anandexcels.wordpress.com/2012/01/28/sumif-function/

Also suggest you try "google spreadsheet forum" for questions like this. Good luck.

Eddy. - Spreadsheet formulas that build web applications.